# Rotating a bufferedImage changes size of image

Tags: java, image, rotation, bufferedimage

I'm trying to rotate a `bufferedImage` 90° but I can't quite get it done.

I can rotate the image but the resulting image is kind of odd.

1) Black borders on the left and right side

2) A loss of information

Here's an example:

This is the original image.

[image]

After I rotate the image I get this:

[image]

I don't really know what I do wrong here.

This is the code I use to rotate a bufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("landscape.jpg"));
BufferedImage imgIn2 = imgIn;
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2, imgIn2.getWidth() / 2, imgIn2.getHeight() / 2);//(radian,arbit_X,arbit_Y)
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(imgIn2.getHeight(), imgIn2.getWidth(), imgIn2.getType());
        op.filter(imgIn2, rotatedImage);
        ImageIO.write(rotatedImage, "JPEG", new File("testRotation.jpg"));
```

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `AffineTransform#setToQuadrantRotation()` instead?

Comment: @JimGarrison I did not try it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With AffineTransform**

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] arg)throws Exception
    {
        BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/arpit/Desktop/image.jpg"));
        BufferedImage imgIn2 =  new BufferedImage(imgIn.getHeight(), imgIn.getWidth(), imgIn.getType());

        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2, imgIn2.getWidth() / 2, imgIn.getHeight() / 2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        op.filter(imgIn, imgIn2);

        ImageIO.write(imgIn2, "JPEG", new File("/home/arpit/Desktop/testrotated.jpg"));
    }
}
```

**Without AffineTransform**

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] arg)throws Exception
    {
        BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/arpit/Desktop/image.jpg"));
        BufferedImage imgIn2 =  new BufferedImage(imgIn.getHeight(), imgIn.getWidth(), imgIn.getType());

        for(int x=0;x<imgIn.getWidth();x++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<imgIn.getHeight();y++)
            {
                int color = imgIn.getRGB(x,y);
                imgIn2.setRGB(imgIn2.getWidth()-1-y,x,color);

            }
        }
        ImageIO.write(imgIn2, "JPEG", new File("/home/arpit/Desktop/testrotated.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, and is likely to be MUCH slower than using the library transform.

Comment: Ok then, I will update the answer with code using `AffineTransform` class.